# change months name(output) from datetime calender

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I am creating a web app in which i am choosing a date from my Materialangular calender extender

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="mddate" ng-blur="dateformatechanged()" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

and in my controler i am fetching the data like

```
   $scope.datemm = moment($scope.mddate).format('MM');
   $scope.dateyy = moment($scope.mddate).format('YYYY');
   console.log($scope.datemm);
   console.log($scope.dateyy);
```

in my `$scope.datemm` the month will be `01,02,03,04` as per the month i select but i want to fetch data like (`january,february,march,april`)

what i need to do in my controller to change the month output

Comment: Try to use "MMM" or "MMMM".

Comment: I said The Same Thing In My Answer @AmitJamwal

Comment: Yes and I voted for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in your code is fine, but just change one line

```
$scope.datemm = moment($scope.mddate).format('MM');
```

to

```
$scope.datemm = moment($scope.mddate).format('MMM');
```

if you want to print(`jan`)

and

```
$scope.datemm = moment($scope.mddate).format('MMMM');
```

if you want to print (`january`)